# how to avoid cyclic dependency whle using constructor injection

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am using autowired annotation for the dependency injection in my app.
How can I avoid cyclic dependency while using constructor injection.

```
public interface CustomUserRepository {
 void myCustom();
}

public interface UserRepository extends CustomUserRepository {
 ----
}

public class UserRepositoryImpl implements CustomUserRepository {

@Autowired UserRepository self;  //Here I have the Cyclic dependency

}
```

Comment: Show some code and explain in detail what you want and what not.

Comment: Elaborate what you have tried sofar to improve quality of your question.

Comment: Please extend your question by providing example code. In any case, however, you should not have cyclic dependencies as they indicate bad design and mixed responsibilites

Comment: Try googling it first: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/253646/how-to-handle-circular-dependency-in-dependency-injection

Comment: And this: http://www.baeldung.com/circular-dependencies-in-spring

Comment: Can you share the exception stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

Spring does not support cyclic dependencies with constructor injection. The rationale is that an object must be fully initialized before it can be injected.

To resolve the issue make your circular dependency into a property.